# laravel and wordpress on the same domain(laravel in subfolder)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I i have wordpress and laravel app, that should communicate by using AJAX- so they must be on the same domain.

wordpress site should be on the main domain - MYdomain.com.
and my laravel app to be on MYdomain.com/panel .

wordpress .htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond ! ^panel
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

laravel htaccess(mydomain.com/panel)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond ^panel
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

i get Internal Server Error
and the log from apache2 folder is:

```
[Thu Mar 12 15:31:07.596263 2015] [core:alert] [pid 1172] [client     xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:52628] /var/www/panel/.htaccess: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section
```

how to solve it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main .htaccess like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/panel [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

In the panel folder change your rules to be like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /panel/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: the problem is not fix, i get the same error in logs,

Comment: Edit your question and post the entire contents of both .htaccess files. There is a mistake in there somewhere.

Comment: the content of .htaccess files the same as you post ( i took your files and paste them in my files) .

Comment: So you don't have anything else in those files but these rules?

Comment: correct. this is the only text i have in my htaccess.

Comment: Delete both files, recreate them with these rules and clear your cache and see if you still get the error. Use notepad

Comment: after delete the files, and re create them. its fix! tnx