# How to install wordpress in laravel public folder

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-5.4

i also follow this link but this is not my solution - [laravel and wordpress on the same domain(laravel in subfolder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018742/laravel-and-wordpress-on-the-same-domainlaravel-in-subfolder)
i want to add wordpress in my laravel site. 
so i install all wordpress in my laravel's public folders. here i create one folder "blog" and in this folder i install my wordpress site.

but my problem is when i run my wordpress site like that localhost:8000/blog it work fine

But when i am try to oprn another link then laravel redirect me 404 page not found.

so how to run wordpress in laravel if make any changes in any file so please any one help me.

**my laravel public folder's .htaccess look like that**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel and wordpress on the same domain(laravel in subfolder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018742/laravel-and-wordpress-on-the-same-domainlaravel-in-subfolder)

Comment: i follow abov llink also but this is not my solution

Comment: This reference might assist you: https://github.com/corcel/corcel

Comment: Best Way to set Blog in Laravel Project https://medium.com/@Madgeek_in/how-to-install-a-wordpress-blog-to-your-laravel-web-application-24e79036ce77

Answer (score 7):

To run wordpress as subdirectory, you must change the .htaccess file inside worpress directory like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Follow this guide for more information
https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/

Answer (score 1):

Well that quite simple if you have a laravel application such as laravel.
What you have to do is just:

1. download wordpress form wordpress.org
2. rename that downloaded wordpress folder to any name such as blog
3. put that blog folder into a public directory of laravel
4. put database credential of wordpress blog into wp-config.php
5. as well as put laravel db credential in .env
6. make change in `.htaccess` of laravel

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://localhost/laravel/public/$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://localhost/laravel/public/$
   RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog/index.php [L] 
   </IfModule>
   ```
7. You can easily access your blog as 
   http://localhost/laravel/public/blog
8. It will start wordpress blog

Comment: How to remove public before blog ?