# Laravel throws 404 when Wordress is attached to it's public folder

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I have a Laravel app available on the root and I want to attach an Wordpress blog to it's public path public/blog. I managed to get it working partially, the admin area and the blog page are working, but every time I go to a post I get a 404 not found thrown by the Laravel app.

Here is my laravel htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect www to non-www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is the blog .htaccess (laravel_app/public/blog/.htaccess)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347249/how-to-install-wordpress-in-laravel-public-folder

Comment: You need to exclude the `/blog` subdomain from Laravel's routing, which you could do by adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog` after the line `#Redirect Trailing...`

Comment: Add it after `#Handle Front` as that is the bit which redirects to the index file.

Comment: @lufc Partially it's working. Whenever I change the Permalink structure to clean urls (blog/sample-post) Laravel keeps throwing 404.